# Magento 2 : How to override core js in Extension?

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, requirejs

In magento 1.X we can check my exention is enabled or not in xml via below kind of code.

```
<action method="removeItem" ifconfig="easylife_switcher/settings/enabled">
      <type>skin_js</type>
      <name>js/configurableswatches/product-media.js</name>
</action>
```

is there any way in magento 2.0 so that I can check my extension is enabled or not from config.

I was override `Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service.js` in my custom module using `require-config.js`. At one point i was face issue on disabling my custom module.

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service' :
              '{namespace}_{modulename}/js/model/shipping-service'
    }
}};
```

After disabling my custom module i want to call core `shipping-service.js` instead of mine overridden.

Answer (score 1):

### Check enable or disable from admin config - ifconfig

We can do the same way as Magento 1: `vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml`

```
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active" name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">wishlist</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Wish List</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

### Disabling Js custom module

We should disable module via [command line](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html): `magento module:disable Yourcustom_Module`.

Overridden Js files will be loaded via Require Js under `pub/static/_requirejs`. So we need to delete this file. This file will be generated automatically again. However, your overridden js will not be added again after disabling module.

Comment: Yes, its true. but i want to disable from config. Is there any way to disable js from config? or can i write condition in require-config, if yes. then how?